# how to know if emit from server to specific client is success or failed? #socketio

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, promise, socket.io

i'am trying to get callback from socket event to client, is case if packet never or fail send to client.

but i got this error, please help

iam using

```
"socket.io": "^2.4.1"
```

this is socket listen to event "from_client", and call function "packet_from_client"

```
     socket.on('from_client', async function(packet) {
        packet_from_client(socket,packet);
     });
```

this is function "packet_from_client",

```
async function packet_from_client(socket,packet) {
    var json_msg = JSON.parse(packet);
    var user_receiver = await search_userby_user_id(json_msg.user_id_receiver);
    if (user_receiver.length > 0) {
        // IF I USING THIS I GOT ERROR NO #1
        await socket.to(user_receiver[0].socket_id).emit("from_server", packet).then((e) => {
            console.log(e);
        });
        // IF I USING THIS I GOT ERROR NO #2
           socket.to(user_receiver[0].socket_id).emit("from_server", packet, async function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        });

  }     
}
```

ERROR NO #1

```
(node:8428) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: socket.to(...).emit(...).then is not a function
    at packet_from_client (E:\PROGRAMING\--------- PROJECT\ChatApp\socket_server\socket_server\server.js:186:90)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:8428) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:8428) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

ERROR NO #2

```
(node:13748) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Callbacks are not supported when broadcasting
    at Namespace.emit (E:\PROGRAMING\--------- PROJECT\ChatApp\socket_server\socket_server\node_modules\socket.io\lib\namespace.js:224:11)
    at packet_from_client (E:\PROGRAMING\--------- PROJECT\ChatApp\socket_server\socket_server\server.js:190:52)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:13748) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:13748) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: anybody can tell me how to solve this?

Comment: Did u read the error message carefully?

Comment: error 2 is "Callbacks are not supported when broadcasting", but i send it to specific client, i confused